# Project Euler #3 Scheme, Largest Prime Factor not changing

Tags: scheme, lisp, prime-factoring

I've been attempting to work through the Project Euler problems in Scheme, and I've written this for problem #3:

```
(define (largest-prime n c lf)
    (define (is-factor? n f)
        (if (= (remainder n f) 0)
            #t #f))

    (define (is-prime? n c)
        (cond
            ((= c 1) #t)
            (else
                (if (= (remainder n c) 0) #f
                    (is-prime? n (- c 1))))))
    
    (display `(counter: ,c current largest factor: ,lf))
    (newline)
    (cond
        ((= c n) lf)
        (else
            (if (and (is-factor? n c) (is-prime? c c))
                (largest-prime n (+ c 1) c)
                (largest-prime n (+ c 1) lf)))))

(display `(largest prime: ,(largest-prime 600851475143 1 0)))
```

The output to which is a large block of text (which is displayed for the purpose of tracking the program's progress), an example line of which is:

```
(counter: 245337 current largest factor: 1)
```

My problem is that, no matter what value the counter is set at, the largest factor does not increase. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(is-prime? c c)` will always return `#f`, except when `c` is 1. Since you think 1 is the only prime, of course it is also every number's largest prime factor.